# Modify header of an excel file using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an list of dates and I am trying to put that dates as a header of excel file.
I have tried using Dataframe and  dict but it's overwriting the file and employee names removed from the excel which I don't want. This is Sample excel Header Image:

[image: Sample excel Header Image]

and the following **code**:

```
dates = ['13-Dec', '20-Dec', '27-Dec', '03-Jan', '10-Jan']
df = pd.read_excel('C://Users//AMANSHAW//Desktop//color_it.xlsx')
df.columns = dates
df.rename(columns = dates , inplace=True)
```

**Error**:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Docs - you should better use a dictionary to be clear:

```
dates = {'A': '13-Dec', 'B': '20-Dec', 'C': '27-Dec', 'D': '03-Jan', 'E', '10-Jan'}
df = pd.read_excel('C://Users//AMANSHAW//Desktop//color_it.xlsx')
df.columns = dates
df.rename(columns = dates, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Getting this error, ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 5 elements. Since excel have only one column I  won't directly be able to add headers to columns that don't exist.

Comment: so you want to replace column headers to cloumns that don't exist? or do you just want to replace as much as headers that exists?

Answer (score 0):

From the image you have attached, your data only has one column, so you won't directly be able to add headers to columns that don't exist. I suggest you do the following to add empty columns and give them the headers:

```
dates = ['13-Dec', '20-Dec', '27-Dec', '03-Jan', '10-Jan']
df = pd.read_excel('C://Users//AMANSHAW//Desktop//color_it.xlsx')
for date in dates:
    df[date] = np.nan   # or df[date] = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to add new empty columns

```
df = df.reindex(columns= df.columns.to_list() + dates)
```

Comment: I tried this but it appending header, what I want to do is, every time i run script I will get a new list of dates and I want that dates as a header of excel, Member column remain same, from column B dates will be as header. Check Sample header image for reference

Comment: You can store in another temporary dataframe and keep original as it is. `df_temp = df.reindex(columns= df.columns.to_list() + dates)`